# StackOverflowException in nested loop in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow, nested-loops

In Unity c#, I am getting data from json and I am finding/comparing gameobject using nested loop (as following code) to set that data in local gameobjects. But I get StackOverflowException error after getting to certain high number of objects(something > 275). Basically 80 time loop runs 10 time which runs 300 times, please see code below.(Note: this code runs okay in lower numbers like when j < 275).

```
public void SetDataInObject()
    {
        if (j < ObjList.objects.Count)  //count is approx 300
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < allObjs.Length; k++)  // Length is 10
            {                
                stCalc = uiMana.floorStats[k].GetComponent<StatesCalc>();

                for (int m = 0; m < allObjs[k].floorObjs.Length; m++)  //Length is 80
                {
                    string serverObj = ObjList.objects[j].name;
                    string localObj = allObjs[k].floorObjs[m].gameObject.name;

                    if (localObj == serverObj)
                    {
                        ObjManager curObjManger = allObjs[k].floorObjs[m].GetComponent<ObjManager>();
                        //Logic to set data in local objects
                    }
                }                
            }
            j++;
            SetDataInObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what will happen with a recursive method if it ends up having a deep call stack.  You might want to try to switch to an iterative approach.

Comment: Also `j` seems like it should be a local variable.  Having a field variable that you basically use as an indexer for a method is a bad idea.  If you need to control where it starts then you can pass that to the function instead.

Comment: An iterative approach would be to change the first line to `while(j < ObjList.objects.Count)` and remove the recursive call `SetDataInObject`, but I don't see how that would help here - I don't see any objects being created that would persist through recursive calls (but I've been up all night, so it's certainly possible!)

Comment: Agreed with juharr .. if something you probably would rather pass `j+1` as a parameter to `SetDataInObject(int j)`. Or what is the reason for not having `for(var j = 0; j < ObjList.objects.Count; j++)`? I don't see any line where you would change that list anyway. Also calling `GetComponent` repeatedly is very expensive .. if anyhow possible you should cache these beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Your inner block runs about `300 * 10 * 80 = 240000` times recursive, stores some values multiple times and additionally needs some longer parsing in order to understand what is done there.

Actually I don't see any place where you would alter the `ObjList.objects` within your method.. so what speaks against simply using a closed loop without any recursion and "magic" index fields:

```
public void SetDataInObjects()
{
    for (var j = 0; j < ObjList.objects.Count; j++)
    {
        // This actually stays the same for all inner iterations until j is changed
        // so keep it around as long as possible to save resources
        var serverObj = ObjList.objects[j].name;

        for (int k = 0; k < allObjs.Length; k++)  // Length is 10
        {                
            stCalc = uiMana.floorStats[k].GetComponent<StatesCalc>();
            // Also this stays the same until k is changed
            // so keep the reference around to save access calls
            var currentObj = allObjs[k];

            for (int m = 0; m < currentObj.floorObjs.Length; m++)  //Length is 80
            {
                var localObj = currentObj.floorObjs[m].gameObject.name;

                if (localObj == serverObj)
                {
                    ObjManager curObjManger = allObjs[k].floorObjs[m].GetComponent<ObjManager>();
                    //Logic to set data in local objects
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

The variables you store are simple types like `int`, `string` and a `Component` reference .. nothing too complex the GC should be concerned with.

Actually this would be even better solved in my opinion by not using indices for `j` and `m` at all

```
public void SetDataInObjects()
{
    foreach(var serverObj in ObjList.objects)
    {
        var serverName = serverObj.name;

        for (int k = 0; k < allObjs.Length; k++)  // Length is 10
        {                
            stCalc = uiMana.floorStats[k].GetComponent<StatesCalc>();
            // Also this stays the same until k is changed
            // so keep the reference around to save access calls
            var currentObj = allObjs[k];

            foreach (var floorObj in currentObj.floorObjs)  //Length is 80
            {
                if (localObjName.Equals(serverName))
                {
                    var curObjManger = floorObj.GetComponent<ObjManager>();
                    //Logic to set data in local objects
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

This will obviously still run the inner block `300 * 10 * 80 = 240000` times but using local variables that are cleared after each according iteration so they are not increasingly allocating memory.

Note that still calling `GetComponent` repeatedly is very expensive, if anyhow possible you should store the references beforehand.

E.g. by making the type of `floorStats` directly a `StatesCalc[]` and the type of `floorObjs` a `ObjectManager[]`, assuming you reference these via the Inspector it will automatically store the according type reference so no `GetComponent` is required on runtime.

Comment: Optimized according to you guys and worked like a charm, but one more thing I noticed that surprisingly this problem was happening in PC only, not in mobile devices. Isn't it strange as mobile devices are weaker?